# Exportar variables a CSV en Genexus

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando en GX15 y tengo una serie de variables que obtengo de otro software.
Necesito saber como pasar dichos valores a un csv y usar este archivo como 'Base de Datos'.
No estoy usando transacciones, solo variables.
Se que en otros lenguajes de programación se puede exportar las variables a un csv y usarlo como DB pero en Genexus no encontré documentación.
Quiero agregar un vento boton que mande los valores de las variables del WP a un mismo archivo Excel para usarlo como DB.
Podrían decirme como hacerlo o recomendarme documentación?

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta tiene 2 partes, como generar un CSV o un Excel y como usarlo como Base de Datos.
Para enviar datos desde una aplicación Genexus a CSV puedes utilizar el [Export Pattern](https://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?csvexportpattern,en) que está en el MarketPlace que te generará los procedimientos para la exportación como se indica en la [Documentación](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27347,CSV%20export%20pattern,).
Para generar un excel desde Genexus, puedes utilizar el tipo de datos [ExcelDocument](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2476,ExcelDocument%20data%20type) y así generar un archivo excel, por ejemplo:

```
&Filename = !"Archivo-" + &Random.ToString().Trim() + !".xls"
&ExcelDocument.Open(&Filename)
&ExcelDocument.Clear()
&ExcelDocument.Cells(1, 1).Text = 'Texto celda A1'
&ExcelDocument.Save()
&ExcelDocument.Close()
```

Y para leerlo, puedes en un WebPanel incluir un control de tipo FileControl y leerlo así:

```
&FileName = &FileControl.ToString()
&ArchExcel.ReadOnly = 1 //el archivo es de solo lectura
&ArchExcel.Open(&FileName)
if &ArchExcel.ErrCode <> 0 
    msg(&ArchExcel.ErrDescription) 
else
    &DatoCeldaA1 = &ArchExcel.Cells(1,1).Text
endif
```

Yendo a la segunda parte de tu pregunta, Genexus no permite usar un CSV o Excel como base de datos, lo mejor que podrías hacer es leerlo en un SDT con el ejemplo de lectura que te puse más arriba y luego vía programación manejar ese SDT.